# Assigning CTRL + T as a shortcut in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, resharper, keyboard-shortcuts

Coming from Eclipse and now working in Visual Studio I was trying to assign my hotkey bindings to the same ones I used to have in Eclipse. I have Resharper installed, too.

I've assigned <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to "Type Hierarchy" but it still seems to respond as it did just before : it expects me to press another key, as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> is being identified as a combo.

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: where did you change it, in Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Keyboard ?

Comment: normally, it works fine with me. I set up Resharper options -> Apply Scheme I want (Visual Studio in my case) -> then go environment, keyboard, the shortcut I want to override -> Remove old shortcut -> Assign new shortcut -> then the first time I use it, it asks me which shortcut I want to use and it works from now on

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First off, if you're so used to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, at least set it to invoke "Inspect This" (ReSharper.ReSharper_InspectThis in VS options), which brings up a drop-down letting you choose between Type Hierarchy, Call and Value Tracking.

As to shortcut assignment, I'm guessing that you have IntelliJ keymap set up in ReSharper. If that's the case, in order to have <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> reassigned, you'll have to ruin the entire range of ReSharper's unit testing shortcuts:

[image]

If you switch to VS keymap (ReSharper > Options > Environment > Keyboard & Menus > Visual Studio > Apply scheme), it gets substantially better as in all contexts (except for XAML UI Designer for some reason) VS won't expect <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to be a part of a combo:
[image]

You'll still have to transfer a fundamental ReSharper shortcut which is Go To Type to another shortcut but this is less pain than killing the entire unit testing subsystem.

Last but not least, if you're going to stay with Visual Studio for long, try force yourself to use any of the two standard ReSharper keymaps. ReSharper documentation and ReSharper users talk shortcuts, which sets you up for a hard time learning and communicating.

Comment: Thanks! I *still* don't know for how long I'll be using Visual Studio. I'm a bit afraid I'll start confusing Eclipse's shortcuts for Resharper's/Visual Studio's shortcuts, but maybe this is just non-sense. I've never before used two sets of shortcuts in parallel, but maybe this isn't a problem.

Comment: I think that even if you're eventually forced to switch between the two tools again, restoring a previously learned keymap shouldn't be a big problem, especially if you take a bit of your time and use a shortcut training service like https://www.shortcutfoo.com/ (it provides drills for Eclipse, ReSharper, and IntelliJ users among others)

Comment: I wasn't aware of the existence of that site!